# Handling data gap in new SoilGrids datasets

Tags: soilgrids

I am working with the latest SoilGrids clay and OCS datasets, but notice a gap in Russia (180deg) when I export the datasets.

Do you have a recommendation how to fill this gap?

Did something happen when exporting?

1. To export I open the dataset in QGIS and export the dataset in Homosoline projection
2. When I import into GEE it shows the below gap, with values of 0.

[image: SoilGrids 2019 gaps]

Comment: This looks like a projection issue based on the jagged triangles at 180 degrees. Is Homosoline the original projection? If not, are you using an appropriate transformation?

Comment: Yes Homosoline was the original projection, but we need to reproject to load into GEE. That must be the issue. I will test and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @Monica Noon can you please share the PROJ string of the CRS you are transforming the map into?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a sliver missing along 180º E in the maps published in December of 2019. Screenshots below from Russia and New Zealand:

[image]

It is about 50 km wide, but it looks like the projection you are using is expanding it considerably.

The cause is a rogue environmental co-variate that for some reason is incomplete. This co-variate is no longer in use and thus the sliver will not be present in the upcoming SoilGrids release.

As for the triangles, they are probably an artifact of the software you used to re-project the maps. There is some evidence that GDAL could be introducing features like these, but so far not in the scale you show. I will continue investigating this problem and eventually file a bug report. That being the case, I shall add a link here.

Comment: Thanks, we look forward to the new release!