# Remaining gaps in SoilGrids250m v2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, soilgrids, homolosine

I am following up on [Handling data gap in new SoilGrids datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355102/how-to-handle-data-gap-in-new-soilgrids-datasets) which is a similar question about a previous version of SoilGrids250m v2.

There still appears to be gaps in northeastern Russia in the most recent SoilGrids250m version, including in the [online viewer](https://soilgrids.org/):
[image: Screenshot from online viewer].

I have the same issue after downloading the entire dataset and re-projecting it to WGS84 or Winkel Tripel in ArcGIS.

Any clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original predictions there is a small triangle with missing data in the northeast of Russia. This appears to be an artifact introduced by GDAL, some sort of blind spot that the programme is not able to process. A bug report will eventually be submitted.

This triangle is blown out of proportion when the original maps are re-projected with a non-equal area projection, as is the case.